# How can i change focus of item inside RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I have two items containing: `EditText` inside `RecyclerView`.

I want to change focus from one item to another when text is written inside this `EditText`. I cant do it in `onBindViewHolder` or `ViewHolder` itself, because it will throw:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while
>   RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Requesting or clearing focus of EditText inside onBindViewHolder is not a good approach.

These two items are inside `RecyclerView` as two `SearchViews` which are logically connected to each other. If I make some changes to **first item**, it will affect layout of the **second one**. Changing focus on demand is something what I need to do frequently. But views can be recycled, so `ViewHolder` do not always presenting that exact `SearchView` to what I want to focus at the moment. For example if one of the `SearchView` is not visible on a screen.

Comment: In general, `requestFocus()` should work fine. Can you please post your RecyclerView adapter code.